# To link website logo to external url from backend interface in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

Need to link website logo to external url from backend interface in drupal 7.

Now I hard coded it to my page.tpl.php file.

Is there any option to add it from backend?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no default option for linking website logo to the external URL.

We need to create a field in the back end for theme settings.

1. Create a page theme-settings.php just inside theme folder with the following code

   function theme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) {

   $form['theme_settings'] = array(

   ```
   '#type' => 'fieldset',

   '#title' => t('Theme settings')
   ```

   );

$form['theme_settings']['theme_logourl'] = array(

```
    '#type'          => 'textfield',

    '#title'         => t('Logo url'),

    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('theme_logourl'),

    '#description'   => t("Logo url for external linking"),

  );
  return $form;

}
```

1. Go and check to the theme settings page - appearance/settings/theme

   There will be a new text filed to enter the external url

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 you can refer to *[this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/1254640)*: In the `template.php` file, change `<front>` to whatever link you like. ( is a Drupal shortcut for the frontpage url)